# cts:search with faceted option not working

Tags: marklogic

I have tried following simple query :

```
let $options := (
  'faceted'
)
return cts:search(collection(),"Review",$options)
```

Its giving me [1.0-ml] XDMP-OPTION: cts:search(fn:collection(), "Review", "faceted") -- Invalid option "faceted".

From ML documentation i found this as a valid option. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

It should be a valid option, supported in at least 5.0 and higher. Are you by any chance running an older version?

Apart from that, the 'faceted' options is just an optimisation flag. You still need to use functions like cts:element-values() and cts:frequency() to get facet values and their count..

The docs on cts:search can be found here: http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search

Some examples on how to generate facet info can be found here: http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:frequency

You might also want to check out the search library, which adds some powerfull features like integrated facet calculation, and pagination:

http://docs.marklogic.com/search:search

Particularly the search:search functions and related ones are probably very much worth while investigating..

HTH!